# Issues using PHP Guzzle in browser

Tags: php, api, composer-php, guzzle

I'm working with Guzzle for the Intercom.io API using PHP. After much wrangling I can run a few basic API calls when I write a script and run it in the terminal, but I don't have any such luck when I run that same script in my browser.

I'm sure its an easy fix I just haven't worked with this before and don't know what I'm doing

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Intercom\IntercomBasicAuthClient;


$intercom = IntercomBasicAuthClient::factory(array(
    'app_id' => 'hidden',
    'api_key' => 'hidden'
));

$a = $intercom->getUsers();
echo $a;

echo 'Hello';
```

In the terminal it outputs the object just fine, in the browser I don't even see "Hello".

Comment: Maybe the PHP on your server does not have cURL or allow_url_fopen is set to Off? Check if the logs say anything (also, set "display_errors" to "On" and show all errors)

Comment: I have this set `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`, but its not giving me anything to go on.

Comment: If it runs inside the shell, it works. Fact that your browser doesn't show up anything means that there's something wrong with the communication client/server. Is apache/ngnix properly configured? Virtualhosts are working? What is the output if you put `phpinfo()`?

Comment: @jnardiello here is the output for `phpinfo()` http://ryangrush.com/hosting/guzzle.png

Comment: @RyanGrush you're using PHP 5.2, but Guzzle says it requires 5.4

Comment: @RyanGrush can I write that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Guzzle's docs](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html#requirements), you need to have at least PHP 5.4 installed. However, from your screen of a `phpinfo()` your server is running PHP 5.2.